# What kind of statistical significant test is suitable for ecology data?

Tags: statistics

In one of the study, we have counted the number of birds in two locations. One is control station; Another one is the area where enhancement has been done. And we have data for 12 months.

If I want to do a test on whether the enhancement is effective, what kind of statistical tests are suitable?

Please let me know if further information is needed.